# Activity object referenced null in onViewCreated?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, viewpage

I am writing an `PageViewer` implementation using `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Fragment child uses Activity reference in `onViewCreated(..){}` which is get from `onAttach(Activity activity){}`

```
private ScreenSlideActivity parentActivity = null; 

@Override   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    parentActivity = (SlideActivity) parentActivity; 
}
```

Now I am trying to use this parentActivity Object in onViewCreated() which is returning me null.

Any suggestion if I am missing anything while maintaining ViewPager behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> parentActivity = (SlideActivity) parentActivity;
> ```

You're assigning a variable into itself which doesn't really change anything. A null will remain null.

You probably wanted:

```
parentActivity = (SlideActivity) activity;
```